# Unable to delete Routes in Namespace using Fabric8 Api

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, fabric8

There are various ways to delete a route

openshiftClient.routes().inNamespace().withName("RouteName").delete();
openshiftClient.routes().inNamespace().withLabel("RouteLabel").delete();

If I use the same Route Yaml in order to delete a route from openshift

openshiftClient.resource(hasMetaData).delete();
openshift.load(Inputstream).delete();

this also does not work

I have used openshift versions 4.6+

Comment: Umm, why are you not specifying namespace in `inNamespace()` method?

Comment: I forgot to specify namespace while writing the question, please assume there is a namespace string

Comment: Which version of Fabric8 OpenShift Client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some syntax mistake in the way you're deleting `Route`. Since Route is a namespaced resource, you need to specify namespace in which the Route exists too for any operation whether it's `get()`, `delete()`, `patch()` etc:

```java
try (OpenShiftClient openshiftClient = new DefaultOpenShiftClient()) {
    openshiftClient.routes().inNamespace("default").withName("random-generator").delete();
}
```

I tested the above code on [CRC](https://github.com/code-ready/crc) (based on OpenShift 4.7.11) and it seems to be working okay.

Comment: I also delete it in a similar fashion but it doesn't work for me....can you please verify for openshift version 4.7.16....

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have access to OpenShift 4.7.16 cluster. I think it should work the same way like it does on any OpenShift version, We have integration tests which verify Route get successfully deleted: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-itests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/openshift/RouteIT.java#L95

Comment: Are you able to delete Route with `oc delete`? Maybe you're lacking required Role to delete a Route?

Comment: I am able to delete route through oc delete

Comment: strange, do you have some reproducer project which I can try out? Which version of client are you using?

Comment: I am using fabric8 version 5.4.1 and using following code for deletion    k8sItems.parallelStream().map(metadata -> openShiftClient.resource(metadata).delete()).reduce(true, Boolean::logicalAnd);

Comment: every resource object is getting deleted except PVC and routes

Comment: What are the contents of `k8sItems`?

Comment: K8Items are resource templates like Routes, PVC, Deployment in form of YAML string

Comment: Could you please share that YAMl manifest on Github Gist or Pastebin so that I can try reproducing?

Comment: Create any two routes in a namespace using openshift UI and try to delete using fabric8 api

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I tried reproducing your issue. I created two routes in OpenShift(https://developers.redhat.com/developer-sandbox instance) UI and tried deleting them using fabric8. For me it seems to work. Here is what I did: https://github.com/rohanKanojia/kubernetes-client-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/io/fabric8/openshift/RouteDeletion.java#L15